# How to handle nullpointer exception?

Tags: java

i have the code below in my java class .

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package webservice;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


public class Webservice {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ArrayOfString aar = new ArrayOfString();
        aar.getString().add("1025976002");
        aar.getString().add("1026020904");
        aar.getString().add("1026020704");
        aar.getString().add("1026026201");
        aar.getString().add("1026036901");
        aar.getString().add("");
        ArrayOfStatusContainer status = getStatusList(aar);
        List<StatusContainer> li =  status.getStatusContainer(); 
       Iterator litr=li.listIterator();    
      // System.out.println("Elements in forward directiton");   
       while(litr.hasNext()){  
           StatusContainer test = (StatusContainer)litr.next();
          System.out.println(test.getStatus());       
       } 

    }

    private static ArrayOfStatusContainer getStatusList(webservice.ArrayOfString keys) {
        webservice.AdStatusWS service = new webservice.AdStatusWS();
        webservice.AdStatusWSSoap port = service.getAdStatusWSSoap();
        return port.getStatusList(keys);

    }
}
```

When ever i enter an empty string or enter a duplicate string value i get a nullpointer exception. I have been trying for a while, but i found no solution so far. I have attached a screen shot of the exception below. Stack trace is below:

```
Sent
Booked
Multiple Errors
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
In QC
Need correction client
    at webservice.Webservice.main(Webservice.java:34)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

[image]

Comment: Use a debugger, step through you code, identify where the `null` reference is coming from and correct it if it is invalid.

Comment: Stack trace please ? Image is not clear.

Comment: What is this, debugging for ants?

Comment: `System.out.println(test.getStatus());`  `test`is `null`. Don't ask me why. Please.

Comment: You have explained very little for a very broad error.

Comment: We see the stack trace.  We just can't read it.  Because we're not ants.

Comment: Debug it, there is no other way! Or on line 34 in webservice.java, if I see correct!

Comment: @nhgrif `right click--> open image in new tab--> click it on.`  That is in Chrome. If firefox, `rightclick--> view image`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ All right, well I learned something new then.  But it's more helpful if the poster just types out the exception as well as pointing us directly to the line it refers to.

Comment: **DO NOT POST IMAGES!!**  To post code or error message listings, copy/paste the text directly into your question, making sure to indent at least four spaces so that it's formatted as "code".  You can do the indentation easily by highlighting the section and pressing the `{}` button.

Comment: OP added and not welly formatted. Just formatted. @OP follow Hot Licks comments from next time onwords.

Comment: And when you post a Java exception message, post the entire message, including the line number information and at least the first few traceback entries.

Comment: What is on line `34`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Console says that the nullpointer exception was throw in line 34, what's possible means that test variable is null and you're trying to access a property of an object null validate null first.

```
 while(litr.hasNext()){  
       StatusContainer test = (StatusContainer)litr.next();
      if(test != null)
          System.out.println(test.getStatus());       
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you always add null checks before accessing a properties from object.